# React Native Loading data problem (Asynchronous)

Tags: react-native, asynchronous, render

I got a problem rendering variable 'html'.
I think its because trying to render it before loading ends( error said the variable 'html' is undefined).

is there any modules or something ? (like loading indicator)

```
return (
<View style={styles.container}>
  <ScrollView style={styles.scrollview}>
    {lecture_render(get_all_list(html))}
  </ScrollView>
</View>
```

)

I rendered like this, but I want some filter for 'html' variable before render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use an `ActivityIndicator` component from `react-native` to render a circular loading indicator if your `state` has been not been set.

```js
import {ActivityIndicator} from 'react-native'
```

```js
if (html=== "") {
  return (
    <View>
      <ActivityIndicator />
    </View>
  );
}

return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <ScrollView style={styles.scrollview}>
      {lecture_render(get_all_list(html))}
    </ScrollView>
  </View>
);
```